# Crushing mode with new user account on PS3

Tags: ps3, uncharted-3

Although I finished Uncharted 3 already with my main account, I recently made a new user account and started playing it again with new user account like you just created a new user.

I finished the game on normal and hard - still no crushing mode on multiplayer. Is it possible that if you make new user account and finish the game on any difficulty, that you will get crushing mode in co-op adventure mode? Do I have to transfer trophies or anything like that?

Comment: While it is possible to do so, we *really* try to encourage proper english, spelling, capitalization, and punctuation here.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that if you make new user account and finish the game
>   on any difficulty, that you will get crushing mode in co-op adventure
>   mode?

If by "finish the game on any difficulty" you're referring to the single player campaign, then no, Single Player Campaign and Multiplayer Co-Op Campaign are different and as such, you need to go through the Hard Mode for each to unlock the Crushing mode.

> Do I have to transfer trophies or anything like that?

You can't transfer any trophies whatsoever, they are fixed in your account for the duration of it.